# Pass data first before deleting a row from a table in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to pass a value from a row in a table before deleting it from the table. I can delete a row using this code:

```
$('#tbl_items').on('click', '#btn_delete', function () {
   $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

but I need to get the value first before actually deleting it. This is how I create the table:

```
if (item.Items != null)
{
    foreach (var itemOnList in item.Items)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => itemOnList.ItemId)</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => itemOnList.ItemName)</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => itemOnList.SerialNumber)</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => itemOnList.BrandName)</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => itemOnList.Quantity)</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => itemOnList.Description)</td>
            <td>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="editItem(@itemOnList.ItemId)">Edit |</a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="deleteItem(@itemOnList.ItemId)" id="btn_delete">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

I need to have code that resembles this

```
$('#tbl_items').on('click', '.btn_delete', function() {
    var self = $(this);

    alert($(this).data('itemid'));
    self.closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Identifiers in HTML must be unique*, so use [Class selector `$('.class')`](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) to bind event handler and as you are already using unobtrusive event handler get rid of inline click handler.

`data-*`prefixed custom attribute can be used to persist arbitrary data with the element, which can be retrieved using [`.data(key)`](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data2).

*HTML*

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-itemid="@itemOnList.ItemId" class="btn_delete">Delete</a>
```

*Script*

```
$('#tbl_items').on('click', '.btn_delete', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var self = $(this);
    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: '@Url.Action("DeleteItem","Item")?=' + self.data('itemid'),
       success: function(result) {
            if (result === true) {
                 self.closest('tr').remove();
            }
       }
   })
});
```

Note: I would recommend you to use `<button>` instead of `<a>`

Comment: @Ibanez1700, Have you updated HTML? Notice I have added class and `data-itemid="@itemOnList.ItemId"`

Comment: I didn't see that. Sorry. Thank you for a great technique!

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the id already, change this line `$(this).closest('tr').remove();`

to `$('#' + itemId).closest('tr').remove();`